# Exiting itertool.product loop when appropriate

Tags: python, python-3.x, passwords, python-itertools

```
printable = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'

unknown = "abcd"

[''.join(i) for i in itertools.product(printable, repeat = 4)]
```

I am trying to find a way to embed something in the itertool line that will do this:

```
if i == unknown:
    print("the unknown was", i)
```

then break the loop. The reasoning for this is that i want to have the ability of searching for longer words without the memory filling up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

List comprehensions aren't really meant for this task -- they're meant for creating lists!

It looks like you want something like:

```
printable = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
unknown = "abcd"

for i in itertools.product(printable, repeat = 4):
    guess = ''.join(i) 
    if guess == unknown:
        print("the unknown was", i)
        break
```

However, if you still want a one-liner you could use generator expressions. Generator expressions are exactly like list comprehensions, except they don't store the next element. We can use them like lists or get the next element with `next(gen)`.

```
printable = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
unknown = "abcd"

correct = next(''.join(i) for i in itertools.product(printable, repeat = 4) if ''.join(i) == unknown)
print("the unknown was", correct)
```